# Reduce timeout for creation of question in Android app

Tags: discussion, android-app

In using the Android app for the first time today, I quickly discovered several things that I would like to suggest for improvement.  Being a dedicated SOer and dutiful alpha tester, I tried to use the Android app to post these questions here to Meta.

Which leads me to this question. I composed my second question and hit "preview", to be greeted with:

> A creation of question can only be performed once every 900 seconds

Aside from the grammer [sic], the 900 second timeout seems rather long -- 15 minutes.

Can this be reduced, perhaps based on rep?

Comment: The Android app likely uses the undisclosed post creation update to the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/), so I imagine the throttling happens there and isn't likely to change (to prevent abuse from other API programs). But I don't know that for certain.

Comment: +1 being dedicated too, I stumbled upon this and was about to post as well.

Comment: We'll definitely be tweaking this, but it's a bit tricky since it is a public API as Tim points out

Comment: It isn't a big issue for now, please focus on other pressing bugs for now :)

Comment: I wanted to use the app to log bugs about the app. Best way to test is to use it like real users would.  Oh well, will just have wait till API get sorted out.

Comment: [Reputedly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192658/230855) there are plans to reduce the throttling.

Comment: As the mobile apps are no longer supported I'm closing this as no longer reproducable.