# Rate limiting out of whack in Android App

Tags: bug, android-app

I was asked to wait for 900 seconds (!) when I tried to submit a second question from the Android app. Got bugged, went over to the mobile website and had no problems.

- Please have the messages in readable terms ? (seconds /hours etc)
- why the inconsistent rate limiting?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191305/reduce-timeout-for-creation-of-question-in-android-app