# Allow me to preview my post that has issues, on the android app

Tags: bug, android-app

When creating a question, or answer I expect, I can't preview my post if I can't post it. For example I can't preview this as I posted another question within 900 seconds.

Comment: As the mobile apps are no longer supported I'm closing this as no longer reproducable.

Answer (score 1):

The current throttles that are in place for the write API are for early protection only.  We do plan on reducing them as well as adding a lot more sanity checks to keep the annoyance level to a minimum while still ensuring that bots won't have free reign to post garbage content.

Comment: I'm not complaining about the throttles, my issue is that I can't preview my post. I guess it doesn't apply so much in my example case as I'd not be able to post anyway, but I can't preview if I don't yet have a title or tags etc

Comment: All we need now is [for the bots to post non-garbage content](http://xkcd.com/810/).