# Comments on own questions

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, android-app

I am answering questions about my questions in comments from my cell. However, I'm getting a message that I can only post 11 comments in 24 hours. Now, I can't answer comments on my questions.

I propose this limit be removed for commenting your own question, so it doesn't appear we are abandoning questions for an entire day. Luckily, one can load the question in the browser to bypass this restriction, but I find the webpage slow. Version 0.1.68.

[image]

Comment: Thats odd, I'm sure I've posted more than 11 comments before. For example today I've posted 25

Comment: I thought I did too, but I'm getting that error now

Comment: It's especially strange that this seems to be mobile only. Which suggests it's a bug

Comment: It's not a new day for another 20 minutes, but I also don't have my computer till tomorrow

Comment: There's a separate rate limit limit for the new writable Stack Exchange API that the app is using. From other posts that have been posted here, the limits are quite a bit lower than the normal desktop website.

Comment: @StevenV Any idea if they will increase that limit?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191305/reduce-timeout-for-creation-of-question-in-android-app makes it seem like it will be revisited at some point

Comment: @StevenV Thanks, I starred that one so I can refer to it later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated, the API both has different throttling than the website and that's something we're considering [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) to modify for the future. For this scenario since I agree that it's very annoying we've gone ahead and bumped the base number of comments people can make using the API so you shouldn't see this again (unless you're really spamming).

Comment: YAY! Thank you @Kasra! May I ask as an aside: how are the limits being determined currently, for the API?